# how to click on button present on card?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

On my screen there is a multiple cards present and On each card different username present. also view profile button available on each card. if i want to click on particular user profile then how could i it? also how could i validate that i am click on right profile name.
eg- harshal- view profile
    vivek -  view profile
    Ram    - view profile
 kishan    - view profile. all these present on separate card. 
so here i want to click ram. How to achieve this.

Here is xpath-->
ram(xpath-html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/strong/span[1])- view profile(xpath- html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/a)

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath locators by text contains:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'yourName')]
```

Sample code

```
this.Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@”http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_tables.htm”);
var expression = By.XPath(“/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[6]/table/tbody“);
this.Wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(expression));
var element = this.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(“//td[contains(text(), ‘5000’)]/preceding-sibling::td[1]“));
Assert.AreEqual<string>(“Ramesh Raman“, element.Text);
```

Find more examples [here](https://automatetheplanet.com/underrated-webdriver-locator-xpath/).

Comment: but how i can assure that i am clicking on exact same name and its profile.Here many username and many view profile button available

Comment: Choose some unique one or arrange your test data so that you always have a unique one. If there are multiple with the same name, there is no way that you can handle it correctly.